# Is there a wildcard endswith for jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery script that changes two href links when the user selects from a drop-downbox.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":input[id*='ddlAttributes']").change(function (event) {
            var masterNumber = $(this)[0].firstElementChild.value;
            var itemNumber = $(this).val();
            $("a[href$=" + masterNumber + "]").each(function() {
                this.href = this.href.replace(masterNumber, itemNumber);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Added html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
            <div class="products">

                        <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6 product">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001'>
                                        <img src='/Handler.ashx?id=BR3001' />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <h4>
                                        <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001'>
                                            BR3001
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                        BR T-ZONE BLACK/SILVER 4.5 [W6]
                                    </p>
                                    <h3 class="text-right">
                                        $0.00
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" style=''>
                                        <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$rptProducts$ctl01$ddlAttributes" id="ContentPlaceHolder_rptProducts_ddlAttributes_0">
    <option value="BR3001">Size</option>
    <option value="BR3001-045">4-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-050">5</option>
    <option value="BR3001-055">5-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-060">6</option>
    <option value="BR3001-065">6-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-070">7</option>
    <option value="BR3001-075">7-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-080">8</option>
    <option value="BR3001-085">8-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-090">9</option>
    <option value="BR3001-095">9-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-100">10</option>
    <option value="BR3001-105">10-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-110">11</option>
    <option value="BR3001-115">11-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-120">12</option>
    <option value="BR3001-130">13</option>
    <option value="BR3001-140">14</option>
    <option value="BR3001-150">15</option>

    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
```

This works the first time the dropdownbox changes. But not on successive changes, because the link has already changed and now won't match the ends with.

Master Numbers are like this: BR3001

Specific Item Numbers are like: BR3001-045, BR3001-050, BR3001-055 etc.

I am trying to get the script to work on successive selection changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the html as well?

Comment: Added html @MUlferts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do here. There may be a better way to use selectors and JQuery though to do what you are looking to do. I added some class and Id selectors to your html and changed the jquery a bit. See the comments in the example below to see another way to use selectors.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(":input[id*='ddlAttributes']").change(function (event) {
            var linkText = "/Product.aspx?Product=";
            var imageSrcBase = "/Handler.ashx?id=";
            var itemNumber = $(this).val();
            
            //Set the actual href of the links using class selector
            $(".productLink").attr("href", linkText + itemNumber);
            
            //Set the img src
            $("#imgLink").attr("src", imageSrcBase + itemNumber);
            
            //Set the link text using itme number
            $("#numLink").text(itemNumber);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
        <div class="products">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 product">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001' class="productLink">
                              <img src='/Handler.ashx?id=BR3001' id="imgLink" />
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <h4>
                              <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001' id="numLink" class="productLink">
                                  BR3001
                              </a>
                          </h4>
                          <p>
                              BR T-ZONE BLACK/SILVER 4.5 [W6]
                          </p>
                          <h3 class="text-right">
                              $0.00
                          </h3>
                          <div class="col-xs-6" style=''>
                              <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$rptProducts$ctl01$ddlAttributes" id="ContentPlaceHolder_rptProducts_ddlAttributes_0">
    <option value="BR3001">Size</option>
    <option value="BR3001-045">4-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-050">5</option>
    <option value="BR3001-055">5-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-060">6</option>
    <option value="BR3001-065">6-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-070">7</option>
    <option value="BR3001-075">7-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-080">8</option>
    <option value="BR3001-085">8-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-090">9</option>
    <option value="BR3001-095">9-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-100">10</option>
    <option value="BR3001-105">10-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-110">11</option>
    <option value="BR3001-115">11-1/2</option>
    <option value="BR3001-120">12</option>
    <option value="BR3001-130">13</option>
    <option value="BR3001-140">14</option>
    <option value="BR3001-150">15</option>

    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute contains selector `[name*=”value”]`.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Also you aren't going to want to replace `masterNumber` with `itemNumber`. Rather set your link's href value to `itemNumber`.

See the updated script example below:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":input[id*='ddlAttributes']").change(function (event) {
            var masterNumber = $(this)[0].firstElementChild.value;
            var itemNumber = $(this).val();
   console.log(masterNumber);
            $("a[href*=" + masterNumber + "]").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("href",itemNumber);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and a regex pattern:

```
var regex = new RegExp(masterNumber + '.*$')
$("a").filter((idx, ele) => regex.test(ele.href))
```

Improvements:

instead of:

```
var masterNumber = $(this)[0].firstElementChild.value;
var itemNumber = $(this).val();
```

you can simply:

```
var masterNumber = this.options[0].value;
var itemNumber = this.value;
```

```js
$(":input[id*='ddlAttributes']").change(function (event) {
    var masterNumber = this.options[0].value;
    var itemNumber = this.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(masterNumber + '.*$')
    $("a").filter((idx, ele) => regex.test(ele.href))
             .each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace(masterNumber, itemNumber);
        if (this.text.trim() != '') {
            this.text = itemNumber;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
        <div class="products">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 product">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001'>
                                <img src='/Handler.ashx?id=BR3001'/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <h4>
                                <a href='/Product.aspx?Product=BR3001'>
                                    BR3001
                                </a>
                            </h4>

                            <p>
                                BR T-ZONE BLACK/SILVER 4.5 [W6]
                            </p>

                            <h3 class="text-right">
                                $0.00
                            </h3>

                            <div class="col-xs-6" style=''>
                                <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$rptProducts$ctl01$ddlAttributes"
                                        id="ContentPlaceHolder_rptProducts_ddlAttributes_0">
                                    <option value="BR3001">Size</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-045">4-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-050">5</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-055">5-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-060">6</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-065">6-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-070">7</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-075">7-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-080">8</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-085">8-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-090">9</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-095">9-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-100">10</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-105">10-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-110">11</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-115">11-1/2</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-120">12</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-130">13</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-140">14</option>
                                    <option value="BR3001-150">15</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```